# Speeding up conversion of MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql-5, storage-engine

I've got a mysql 5.1 server with a database of approximately 450 tables, taking up 4GB . The vast majority of these tables (all but 2) are MyIsam. This has been fine for the most part (don't need transactions), but the application has been gaining traffic and certain tables have been impacted because of table-locking on updates. That's the reason 2 of the tables are InnoDB now.

The conversion on the smaller tables (100k rows) don't take long at all, causing minimal downtime. However a few of my tracking tables are approaching 50 million rows. Is there a way to speed up an `ALTER TABLE...ENGINE InnoDB` on large tables? And if not, are there other methods to convert minimizing downtime on these write-heavy tables?

Comment: Something to keep in mind: multiple questions in a single post tend to discourage people who can answer one of the questions from posting an answer.

Comment: I VtC as this is rather complicated to answer. You should open as several questions individually.

Comment: i'll gladly take the advice to make it into a single question, but is it recommended to delete this question and just open a new one? the rewrite would mostly be removing the second 2 bullets and altering the first (I updated the title as well to reflect which storage engines)

Comment: Either would be fine. It's usually _easier_ to write two other questions and delete the one. However, you could just as easily leave this one for "reference" and have the other two refer back to it, as a "this is my overall goal" question.

Comment: edit this one down into one bullet, then post the followup questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me start by saying, I hate ALTER. It's evil, IMHO.

Say, this is your current table schema -

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_of_love (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
my_value VARCHAR(40),
date_created DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here's the path I recommend -

Create a new table object that will replace the old one:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_of_love_NEW (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
my_value VARCHAR(40),
date_created DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
```

Insert all the rows from the old table by name into the new table:

```
INSERT INTO my_table_of_love_NEW (id,my_value,date_created)
SELECT id,my_value,date_created FROM my_table_of_love;
```

Smoke test your migration:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table_of_love_NEW;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table_of_love;
SELECT a.id,a.my_value,a.date_created FROM my_table_of_love_NEW a
LEFT JOIN my_table_of_love b ON (b.id = a.id)
WHERE a.my_value != b.my_value;
```

Swap table names so that you can maintain a back up in case you need to rollback.

```
RENAME TABLE my_table_of_love TO my_table_of_love_OLD;
RENAME TABLE my_table_of_love_NEW TO my_table_of_love;
```

Proceed to regression testing.

This approach becomes more and more preferable with tables with multiple indexes and millions of rows.

Thoughts?

Comment: Agreed ... although if it's heavily transactional, you might need to take the database down while doing this.  (but an alter table's going to give you a longer period of downtime, most likely)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would require downtime for the more active tables. I'm going to have to run some tests, but why would `ALTER TABLE` take longer than `INSERT INTO...SELECT` on 50 million rows?

Comment: It won't.  Basically MySQL does internally exactly as this poster suggested.  It creates a copy of the definition and trickle loads into the copy.

Comment: I like this method because it skips the "copy to tmp" part, which can take some time for large tables.

Comment: Let me just add now, that in MySQL 5.7, ALTERs are much faster and easier to cope with.

Answer (score 7):

1) Loss protection is a function of paranoia. Always make a backup. If you're really paranoid, make a backup then restore from the backup.

2) [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html) of the MySQL manual has instructions to convert table types.

> The fastest way to alter a table to InnoDB is to do the inserts directly to an InnoDB table. That is, use ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=INNODB, or create an empty InnoDB table with identical definitions and insert the rows with INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ....

3) [PostgreSQL does full-text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html), The [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html) Engine seems to do it for MySQL

Comment: i will definitely look into sphinx, as I've only recently heard about it.

Answer (score 3):

It's X times easier to optimize whole server (memory configuration, caches, indexes) when you have only one engine used. Mixing myisam with innodb on large databases will always stuck at some point forced by some comprosise for both engine to work good (but not excelent :)

I recommend You to interest in some dedicated full text search engines like [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), lucene ([solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)) and get rid of it from database layer.